# Unicode characters in /bin/sh VS /bin/bash

Tags: bash, unicode, sh, chars

Please try:

```
bash -c "printf '\u2744'"
bash -c "echo -e '\u2744'"
```

And so:

```
sh -c "printf '\u2744'"
sh -c "echo -e '\u2744'"
```

Why in `/bin/bash` I can get that unicode character but not in `/bin/sh`? How to print a unicode characer (for example `❄`) in `/bin/sh`?

Comment: Because the POSIX sh standard doesn't include Unicode support, so `/bin/sh` isn't required to support it. (Also, the POSIX sh standard doesn't include `echo -e` at all -- one of the few places where bash doesn't just extend the standard, but also breaks it).

Comment: ...see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/echo.html for full notes on `echo`; the APPLICATION USAGE and RATIONALE sections are particularly to the point.

Comment: As for the POSIX spec for `printf` -- laying out the only behavior `/bin/sh` is required to provide -- it's specified at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/printf.html; you'll see no `\u` there either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to print a unicode character in `/bin/sh` (which isn't required by POSIX to support `\u` sequences), either embed it literally in your script or break it down into its component bytes and print those individually.

For the snowflake symbol used in the question:

```
printf '\342\235\204'
```

Now, how do you find those numbers? The easiest way is to use `od` from a shell that *does* support unicode:

```
$ printf '\u2744' | od -b
0000000 342 235 204
```

Comment: Or just use whatever encoding your terminal supports, and be nonportable to other encodings, assuming your `sh` repeats your strings faithfully. These days, hardcoding UTF-8 encoding might not be a big deal.

Answer (score 4):

Because bash only got support for those in the `4.2` release series.

From https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/CHANGES:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
This document details the changes between this version, bash-4.2-alpha,
and the previous version, bash-4.1-release.
....
3.  New Features in Bash
....
d.  $'...', echo, and printf understand \uXXXX and \UXXXXXXXX escape sequences.
```

Comment: Was the question substantially revised since initial post? This is explicitly a question about `/bin/sh`, only mentioning bash for comparison.